# Doctrine querybuilder multiple join

Tags: php, doctrine

I've an error while joining my tables like this :

```
$queryBuilder = $conn->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('*')
             ->from('table1','t1')
             ->innerJoin('t1','table2','t2', 't1.id = t2.id' )
             ->innerJoin('t2','table3','t3', 't2.id = t3.id' )
             ;
$queryBuilder->getSQL();
```

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryException' with message 'The given alias 't2' is not part of any FROM clause table. The currently registered FROM-clause aliases are: t1. Join clauses are bound to from clauses to provide support for mixing of multiple from and join clauses.

Seems the builder only check join linked with the from, not the join linked with other joins, in getSQLForSelect :

```
    if (isset($this->sqlParts['join'][$from['alias']])) {
                foreach ($this->sqlParts['join'][$from['alias']] as $join) {
                        $fromClause .= ' ' . strtoupper($join['joinType'])
                                     . ' JOIN ' . $join['joinTable'] . ' ' . $join['joinAlias']
                                     . ' ON ' . ((string) $join['joinCondition']);
                }
            }
```

Changing this seems to work but it's dirty (and bring others pbs)

```
        if (isset($this->sqlParts['join'])) {
            foreach ($this->sqlParts['join'] as $joins) {
                foreach ($joins as $join) {
                    $fromClause .= ' ' . strtoupper($join['joinType'])
                                 . ' JOIN ' . $join['joinTable'] . ' ' . $join['joinAlias']
                                 . ' ON ' . ((string) $join['joinCondition']);
                }
            }
        }
```